# Copying Row, Losing NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have this working where it will copy the row, and then link the new row to the previous row.

Where my issue is, is in copying over the NULL values. When I run this all null values go into the new row as blank.

How would I get it to change the value to NULL if it was originally NULL?

```
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM rdpricing WHERE psid = '$dupsid';"); 
if($result->num_rows >= "1"){
$count = $result->num_rows;
$cols = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM rdpricing");

while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if (!in_array($r["Field"], array("rdpid", "psid", "rdold"))) { //Excluding these columns
    $cols[] = $r["Field"];
    }
}

// Build and do the insert
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM rdpricing WHERE psid = '$dupsid';"); 

while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO rdpricing (" . implode(", ",$cols) . ", rdold) VALUES ("; 
$count = count($cols);

foreach($cols as $counter=>$col) {

**// This is where I Believe it needs to happen, and what I have attempted, and it is NOT working**

    if(empty($r[$col]) || is_null($r[$col]) || $r[$col] == ""){
        $r[$col] = NULL;
    }

    $insertSQL .= "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($r[$col]) . "'";
    if ($counter < ($count - 1)) {
        $insertSQL .= ", ";
    }
 } // END foreach

 $insertSQL .= ", '".$r["rdpid"]."');";

 $mysqli->query($insertSQL);
 if ($mysqli->affected_rows < 1) {
 printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
}
$new_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE rdpricing SET `psid`=? WHERE `rdpid`=?");
        $statement->bind_param('ss', $new_psid, $new_id);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->close();
}

}
```

Comment: Note: Is it possible to do it in this way: `INSERT INTO rdpricing SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM rdpricing WHERE psid = '$dupsid';` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: The only issue with that, is I am essentially duplicating a shopping cart. There are upwards of 50 columns that are all different for around 20 different product types, and this is a basic way to do them all.

Comment: Tip an actual: You parse the `NULL` value as empty string: You do `$value = null;` but later `'".$value."'` but real null must be as `"$value"` no quotes e.g. `values (null,null,null)` not `values ('null','null','null')`

Comment: Hey, I have also tried removing that top portion and doing

`$insertSQL .=empty($r[$col]) || is_null($r[$col]) || $r[$col] == "" ? "NULL (also tried null for good measure)" : "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($r[$col]) . "'";`

Still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated from info in the comments:

```
#reset/create  before the foreach, create an empty array
$insertSQLValues=array();


#in the foreach do some on given type 
if(is_null($r[$col])){#real null
    $r[$col] = "null";
} else if (empty($r[$col]) || $r[$col] == ""){#empty values
    $r[$col] = "''";
} else {#standart data
    $r[$col] = "'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($r[$col])."'";
}
$insertSQLValues[]=$r[$col];


#later
$insertSQL .= implode(', ',$insertSQLValues).", '".$r["rdpid"]."');";
```

Hopefully you can merge that into your code.

Comment: That was perfect. Almost like I needed to step back and have some fresh eyes on this! Thank you very much!